# How can I break down the memory-only time and computation-only time for a program on Xeon Phi?

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing, intel, xeon-phi

Modern processors overlap memory accesses with computations. I want to study this overlap on Intel Xeon Phi. A conventional way to do so is to modify the code and make two versions: memory-only and computation-only, like the approach used in this slide for GPU: http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2012_GTC2010.pdf.

However, my program has complex control flows and data dependencies. It's very hard for me to make such two versions.

Is there any convenient way to measure this overlap? I'm considering the Vtune profile, but I'm still not sure about what HW counters should I look at.

Comment: I personally don't see the point in doing this sort of analysis at all, since, as you say, modern processors hide the latency of memory fetches by running the processor out of order (and in some cases by having "hyperthreading" that runs a second thread when the first one is waiting for memory or instructions). Separating the memory and processing only really works for trivial programs [matrix multiplication for example], and you have to be careful that the compiler doesn't remove "everything" when you do that. I would just run a profiler (VTune on Windows, perf on Linux)

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's right. But I'm researching on this issue. My goal is to hide more computation in memory accesses. So, I must know for sure about how much computation is already hidden and are the processors doing a good job on this. Any idea on how to use Vtune to check this overlap?

Comment: You'd be looking for "memory read" and "memory write" stalls. Modern compilers tend to be pretty good at shuffling things around to help hide these things too - but the processor itself does a lot more than most compilers.

Comment: The current coprocessor does not do out of order execution, but you still need to take all of  Mats Petersson other points into consideration. Also, don't forget caching which will affect data access time. One other point I would like to make - when I first started working with high performance computers, I was given a piece of compiler generated assembly and told to see if I could do better. One of the first things I tried was doing more work while waiting for data. It's amazing how little it takes to mess up caching and register reuse and cause memory stalls. Sometimes less is more.